# Detecting unused methods iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Very simple question and hopefully isn't duplicated :).

The situation is following:

`Project` has been developing more then a year and by many developers. 
From time to time I'm facing with `unused` methods (which are defined in .h and .m) obviously I'm not getting any `warnings`.

This is not critical, but I would like to have project cleared from all unnecessary staff. Of course I can search for all methods and define which are unused in project but I wonder if there is more elegant way?!

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean - my question isn't clear enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect unused methods and #import in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456966/how-to-detect-unused-methods-and-import-in-objective-c)

Comment: it is clear enough ,as i am too facing the same issue,and manually checking for the Unused method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick way to check while browsing your source code is the *View > Standard Editor > Show Related Items* menu (shortcut key: ^1). Place your cursor within a method body and then view the Callers.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this is not best way to check this. You can call methods using selector or something. And you need to check every method with this. Probably, there is way to check ALL unused methods, functions, etc.

Answer (score 5):

AppCode (http://www.jetbrains.com/objc) can tell you if a method or an import is unused.
It's works in real time, but you can also inspect a whole project (menu code > inspect Code)

[image]

I don't think xCode can do it.
AppCode is not free, but it has a trial version.

Comment: I'm using swift and it doesn't seem to work with Swift, do you know any to enable it for swift? Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Might I suggest adding an NSLOG to these methods. For example, if you have a View Controller called Home, you can go into the .m file for the Home View Controller and at the top of the function, write the following:

```
NSLOG(@"Method 1, has 3 buttons);
```

then watch the readout as you progress through the actions on that View Controller. The log should say something that would best describe the method in question. Step 2 would be to take the methods that you feel aren't showing up on the output and comment them out. That can be done by highlighting the method and then hitting Command + '/' on the keyboard. This will place '//' in front of each highlighted line commenting it out. Test your view controller again and if still no errors, you can delete that method. That's a free way to do it, but it does take some time.

Comment: It's quick, simple, and works. I guess some people would rather work harder than smarter.