# How to find unused code in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456966/how-to-detect-unused-methods-and-import-in-objective-c), but the answer doesn't seem to be valid in Xcode 7. At least I can't find it.

Can anyone tell me where can I tell the compiler to notify me about unused functions/parameters/values ?

Comment: ofcourse compiler will warn you for the unused variable. I am not sure about the unused methods!!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Xcode has a number of settings you can enable to warn you about things like unused functions, parameters, and values.

[image]

You can also easily enable strict warnings by setting your *Other Warning Flags* to `-Wall -Wextra -Weverything`.

Another option for detecting unused code is by [using Code Coverage](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html).

Comment: your link is broken : "Sorry, that page cannot be found"

Comment: @Aleksandr https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html

Comment: this is Wawesome

Comment: could you clarify the ``-Wall -Wextra -Weverything``. when i try to add it as other nothing changes really? thanks

Comment: From my experience these settings do nothing. I just added `func test() { }`, built the project and got no warning about unused function

Comment: @AndreyGordeev I think it only works for Objective-C code, based on this forum post: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/xcode-how-to-find-dead-unused-swift-code.2083604/#post-25454328

Answer (score 12):

In left side select **Project** and in **Build Settings**

Unused functions, parameters, and values

[image: Unused functions, parameters, and values]

Other Warning Flags to -Wall -Wextra -Weverything

[image: Other Warning Flags to -Wall -Wextra -Weverything]

Answer (score 8):

To check the unused functions and variables you can also use the following scripts-

> https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/swift-scripts

Comment: Does this still work? Doesn't look like the script is being maintained.

Answer (score 2):

****2022 Update** | Swift**

Those who are looking for a way to **remove unused code from Swift project**, it can be done easily using Periphery.

Periphery is a tool to remove unused code from Swift projects. It can detect unused function, struct, class, protocols etc.

Its very easy to use. You can get step by step guide here :

[Remove Unsed Code from iOS Swift Project](https://medium.com/@mshcheglov/unused-code-cleanup-in-ios-projects-9789e5d247ca)

Comment: That link is dead. Here is a good article on periphery: https://medium.com/@mshcheglov/unused-code-cleanup-in-ios-projects-9789e5d247ca

Answer (score 1):

For those who are seeking a solution for `Objective-C` codebase like me, try [this script](https://github.com/nst/objc_cover) by @nst. It analyzes the mach-o files.