# OSX XCode : Want the list of all function with there caller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, shell, command-line

I want to find out unused function in objective-c. As due to dynamic nature of objective we cannot get this type of warning as in swift.

But Xcode provides the caller list of a function.

[image]

Is it possible through xcode/osx command line to print all the functions with there caller(s)?

If I further extend this question, Is it possible through xcode/osx command line to print all the functions those have zero caller(s)?

Comment: Look at plugins feature https://github.com/alcatraz/Alcatraz, https://www.raywenderlich.com/94020/creating-an-xcode-plugin-part-1

Comment: Don't forget the calls from the xibs/storyboard. Duplicate of [How to find unused code in Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233564/how-to-find-unused-code-in-xcode-7)?

Comment: @Willeke I used this setting, but not getting warning for same in obj-c

Comment: It's impossible to detect unused methods. The answer mentions Code Coverage.