# Can Xcode notify me about unused variables?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, settings

I would like Xcode to warn me or notify me of unused `variables` and perhaps also `functions`. I have tried the answer given in this thread:

[How to find unused code in Xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233564/how-to-find-unused-code-in-xcode-7)

but in my settings it's already set to yes, so it doesn't seem to work. There's a comment in that thread that says that it only works for `Objective-C`. Perhaps this is the case. Or am I missing something? Or is there another way to implement this error message? I also read that `product<analyze` would reveal the unused variables, but for me nothing happens.

Comment: unused var are flagged in code with a warning, and listed in issues navigator.

Comment: @claude31 My field variables aren't marked by any yellow warnings despite the build setting set to yes :/

Comment: Could you show a complete func, with unused var that is not flagged ?