# How to quickly remove all the unused variables with xCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode3.2

I was wondering if there is a quick and effective way to remove all the unused variables (local, instance, even properties) in xcode... I am doing a code cleanup on my app and if I knew a quick way for code refactoring it would help me a lot...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being a long time since you made your question and maybe you found an answer already, but from an answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960470/profiling-objective-c-binary-image-size):

> For static analysis, I strongly
>   recommend the Clang Static Analyzer
>   (which is happily built into Xcode 3.2
>   on Snow Leopard). Among all its other
>   virtues, this tool can trace code
>   paths an identify chunks of code that
>   cannot possibly be executed, and
>   should either be removed or the
>   surrounding code should be fixed so
>   that it can be called.
>
> For dynamic analysis, I use gcov (with
>   unit testing) to identify which code
>   is actually executed. Coverage reports
>   (read with something like CoverStory)
>   reveal un-executed code, which —
>   coupled with manual examination and
>   testing — can help identify code that
>   may be dead. You do have to tweak some
>   setting and run gcov manually on your
>   binaries. I used this blog post to get
>   started.

Both methodologies are exactly for what you want, detecting unused code (both variables and methods) and removing them.